# Objective C : Get correct float values(justified)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, nsdecimalnumber

I worked a lot in it and can't find a solution. Even the title can't explain clearly.

I have three values weight, quantity and total

I had done the following

```
float wq = [[weightarray objectAtIndex:selectedint]floatValue];
float q = [quantity floatValue];
float total = wq * q;
```

for ex, if

```
[weightarray objectAtIndex:selectedint] = @"3.14";
quantity = 4;
```

then the result is

```
wq = 3.140000  q= 4.000000 total = 12.560000
```

but I need

```
wq = 3.14 total = 12.56
```

what to do?
I searched a lot, someone suggests to use NSDecimal,

```
NSDecimalNumberHandler *roundingBehavior = [NSDecimalNumberHandler decimalNumberHandlerWithRoundingMode:NSRoundPlain scale:2 raiseOnExactness:FALSE raiseOnOverflow:TRUE raiseOnUnderflow:TRUE raiseOnDivideByZero:TRUE];
```

but the scale is not 2 here, wq value may have 3 or four numbers after point.

If the total = 2.30000100 means I need total = 2.300001
how to solve this?

Comment: To clarify - how do you want the figures truncated - to a known number of decimal places or to remove ending zeros - and if the aller how to dea with say 2.3 entered actually being stored as  2.300000001 ?

Comment: I need to remove ending zeros only

Comment: and you are aware that what you have in the string will not necessarily be what is in the float e.g. my  2.3 entered actually being stored as 2.300000001 ?

Comment: if total = 2.0 means I need total = 2 only

Comment: 2.3000000001 is not a problem, it can be as it is, but if there is 2.300000000100 means I need 2.3000000001 as result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a more direct way to achieve it (which I don't know) but here's a suggestion...

1. Convert to string as you already do.
2. Use `[myString hasSuffix:@"0"]` to see if it ends in zero.
3. Use `[myString substringToindex:[myString length]-1]` to create a new string without the final zero.
4. Repeat.

I know it's not elegant, but unless someone has a better solution, this will at least do what you want.

UPDATE: scratch that - I just discovered `[myString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:set]`.  Surely this must be what you need...?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure what it is your asking for, but it seems as if you want the values to only display a 2 d.p. In which case you could use a string format like so:

```
    NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"float = %.2f", 3.14];
```

The .2 specifies that the float should be justified to 2 d.p.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Finally solution found, thanks to Martin

```
float total = 12.56000;
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", total];
NSLog(@"%@",s);
BOOL success;
success =NO;
while(!success)
{
    if ([s hasSuffix:@"0"])
    {
       s = [s substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,[s length]-1)];
    }
    else if ([s hasSuffix:@"."])
    {
        s = [s substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,[s length]-1)];
        success = YES;
    }
    else
        success = YES;
}
NSLog(@"%@",s);
```

if total = 12.560000 it returns total = 12.56

if total = 12.000000 it returns total = 12

if total = 10.000000 it returns total = 10

if total = 12.3000100 it returns total = 12.30001